# Choppy Audio in Car Stereo

Tags: audio, compact-disc

Okay I am not sure that if this is a question that I can ask here, feel free to move this to another forum if its not.

Now I am facing a weird problem, disks that I burn on my PC to play on my car stereo system seem to be playing as choppy and generally low quality sound. While if I play the same disk on my PC the audio is fine.

Now let me tell you I am using Windows Media Player to burn the Audio Disk in a standard Red Book(CD Audio) format. Also I have disabled the volume normalization in Media Player while burning.

Now there is nothing wrong with my car audio since other disks that I have bought seem to play fine. So I don't know where I am going wrong.

I am modifying the audio files that I want to burn in Audacity first(they are mp3 files), and I can verify that they are in stereo format in 16bit PCM when I am saving them.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: the first few things to try are already written up here http://superuser.com/questions/67968/certain-cd-rs-not-working-in-car-sometimes?rq=1 even though the question is slightly different.  You can actually also visibly see a "bad burn" by reflecting a spotty light off the readable surface of the cd (or dvd) and compare it with a burned disk that is working proper in more readers.

Comment: @Psycogeek The data verification process after burning the disc passes, in Nero.

Comment: That is a good start, but to test compatability you would have to verify it in the cars reader :-)  Your indication that the exact same disk plays well on the computer, plus the car having no problem with glass mastered nomal cd, indicates that the reader in the car might be more pickey.  When you indicate it plays "Choppy and generally low quality" that still could be a very large range.  Is it totally unplayable in the car, or barely acceptable and your still doing it?

Comment: @Psycogeek All tracks play. But the sound quality is barely acceptable with a lot of hissing noise. Yes so what magic to I ave to do in order for it work on my car, when it works so well o my PC.

Comment: If you have nero, why dont you at least test by having nero write an "audio cd" from the mp3 data direct, without making any changes. That will see if windows (less controllable) writing program, and any audacity changes, are part of the problem.  Hiss is again a different thing.  If you have any more descriptive terms for what your hearing , do tell.

Comment: @Psycogeek The audio is cracking. A lot of noise. And I have tried Nero. Same Effect.

Comment: Try a different media (brand), burn slow (definitions of slow might be 8x instead of 48x) Nero has those options in the slightly advanced settings prior to hitting the burn button.   Oddly try a CDRW media, as some people (long ago) reported it might be readable in some things where another brand or type might be more compatable in others.The audio screeching and cracking would probably be a data problem. Hiss could just be a audio system that is more sensitive to highs, like has better tweeters than your desktop, or is equalised different by the design of the stereo (even before adjusting)

Comment: @Psycogeek Exactly. How do I burn tracks for my stereo system that is equalized properly. I can't adjust my car audio system but I can equalize my system. Anyway I can do that ?

Comment: a smoothing alogrythm could pull out some hiss and highs, or pre-equalising the files in the audio program. If the files have a bad digital range (low recording), and because of poor range your amplyfying more "noise" then "signal" , then you could increase the digital volume (without peaking) in the audio program.  BUT if this is a data problem, and the reader is not able to read the digital data cleanly, none of that would help.