# Reducing CD burn speed beyond that allowed by Windows Media Player?

Tags: windows, compact-disc, burning, cd-burning

I a trying to burn an audio CD, but I keep getting burn errors.

That is probably because my minimum burn speed is 16x (as detected by Windows Media Player).

How can I reduce the burn speed to 2x or 4x?

Comment: Why do you think it's due to speed? What type of CD do you want to write? What type of hardware do you have? Using what software, in which version of Windows? Without knowing all these we unlikely will be able to help you.

Comment: 16x isn't *terribly* fast these days (it's about [twice the lowest allowed transfer rate for a DVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD#Transfer_rates)). At 2.4 MB/s, it's on the order of 1/30 to 1/50 of a rotational HDD's throughput ability. What makes you think your system is unable to keep up with that during burning?

Comment: @MátéJuhász I want to write an Audio CD. I am on Windows 8.1x64 with the latest OS updates. And I think it is about speed because of this answer http://superuser.com/a/67971/579108

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I have linked an answer from SU in my previous comment. And I am not trying to burn a DVD I am trying to burn an Audio CD.

Comment: I am not saying you are trying to burn a DVD, I'm saying that even reasonably fast burn speeds for CDs are slow in terms of DVDs, and even DVD burn speeds are slow in terms of what modern hard drives can deliver. It's also a good idea to include such references directly into the question because they may influence answers to this question, and certainly saves time for everyone involved.

Comment: That said, did you even try the solution in the very answer you linked to? What were the results? Please [edit] your question to add the information asked for in comments.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I am on a Desktop so no question of a laptop. And my desktop is not giving me a 4x or 2x option. So I can't try that and that's why I am here.

Comment: @Dave My lowest burn speed is 16x. I would love to burn at 2x or 4x but how do I do that if my computer does not provide it. Thats why I asked another question http://superuser.com/q/1061535/579108

Comment: Try a different burning program....https://cdburnerxp.se/en/download

Answer (score 2):

As a musician who records music and produces some, this is something I've looked into in the past. When we provide a master CD for duplication, it is always asked to be burnt at the slowest speed it can. It has **never** been decreed that it must be at a given speed though.

Simply, the issue with fast writes is that not all players can read them. But technology is constantly improving and whilst I'm not saying you won't find examples where this issue still occurs, it's now quite rare (based upon my own experience).

Another factor is what you're burning too. If you go for an non-trusted poor quality disc, then you're likely to have other problems as well. As long as you're burning at the slowest speed and that speed is within the range that disc supports, you should not see any problem.

The actual limitation is down to hardware. Unless you find a way to upgrade the firmware then no, you can't.

To address some points you make in the comments having a lower rate of burn does not mean less errors! In fact, it was believed (and I can't find a source) that 16x speed was the "best" to burn at as it could be read by the majority of CD readers

You may find second hand CD burners which will suffice for your needs (forcing the slower write).

Try different brands of CD, not just a different disc from the same spindle/pack.

Try to burn another set of songs to see if one of the files you're burning is actually faulty and maybe the software can't read the data and is throwing an exception but you're seeing a more generic error message.

Try a different CD burner.